# What shall we do with cross-posted questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Today, I noticed that the question [Where did the energy released due to gravitational binding energy of the Earth go?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/where-did-the-energy-released-due-to-gravitational-binding-energy-of-the-earth-g) was posted word for word just over an hour earlier on Physics.SE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152979/where-did-the-energy-released-due-to-gravitational-binding-energy-of-the-earth-g), where two answers were provided and one accepted.

What should we do in this case where the question is blatantly cross-posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this has been addressed thoroughly in [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)
Personally, I would like the question closed so that the questioner decides carefully what the best site is.

Comment: How about cross posting across different sites i.e. on a non stack exchange site and stack exchange site ?

Comment: @gansub content posted to SE is licensed cc-by-sa. As long as content is attributed, it can be cross posted to any non-SE site.